# after upgrades on ubuntu 18.04, docker tensorflow/gpu image fails to run

Tags: docker, tensorflow, nvidia

I used to run tensorflow/jupyter with the following command:

docker run --gpus all -it -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 -v /home/saus/:/tf/home tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter

Now it fails with the following message:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: Running hook #0:: error running hook: signal: segmentation fault (core dumped), stdout: , stderr:: unknown.
> ERRO[0002] error waiting for container: context canceled

It will run the container fine if I remove the '--gpus all' but of course there are no GPUs available to tensorflow.

Has anyone seen this error?  Got a fix?

M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is resolved.  Further upgrades to docker nvidia packages resolved the problem.

;-)

M.

Comment: Please provide more details on which upgrades solved the problem and why.